# Image turns grey after taking with emulator

Tags: java, android

I am taking photos using emulator on android, the photos are of colour before I take the photo, but when I click capture, the photos are turned into black/white/grey? I am not sure why it is doing this as it works normally when not on my app just using the camera app.

Comment: Can you share your code so maybe it is easier to find problem and help?

Comment: It is just the code from android documentation, it was working fine then all of a sudden has starting turn the images grey

Comment: Please provide a link to the code you are using. Also, some screenshots would help.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do here. The linked code opens the camera app to take the photo. You said "it works normally" when using the camera app. Are you saying it works when you open the camera app from the home screen icon, but not when you open that same app from your own app? Also, what _exact_ procedure are you using to view the image, and determine that it is gray?

Comment: The problem is when I open the camera within my app on the emulator, I will take a photo. When I take the photo, the image turns to grey colour

Comment: The code in the link is how I open the camera and take a photo, just strange to why it is changing colour?

Comment: And it does it on the camera within the phone too, not just the app, i have tried using different phones as emulators and still the same problem

Comment: I view the image using the camera app within my app

Comment: @neymark1234 "camera app within my app": I have no idea what this means. We're gonna need to see some screenshots. Also, upload one of the image files.